# BigQuery SELECT last day of every month on column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset as such

```
Date           TotalAmount
01/10/2020     50,000
31/10/2020     51,000
01/01/2021     80,000
31/10/2021     70,000
28/02/2021     100,000
31/03/2021     990,000
```

I am trying to extract the total amount for the last day of each month on the table just like

```
Date           TotalAmount
31/10/2020     51,000
31/10/2021     70,000
31/03/2021     990,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [last_day](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#last_day):

```
select *
from mytable
where date = last_day(date)
```